# Why DateAdd() and DATEDIFF() gives different result and which is better in performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, ssms

Currently, I am trying to run my sql query in 2 different ways.

`WHERE order_date_time >= DateAdd(month,-3,getdate())`

and

`WHERE DATEDIFF(month,order_date_time,GetDate()) <= 3`

1) Why I am getting 2 different results? Shouldn't I be getting same value as I am trying to find records from last 3 months or less?

Am I not calculating the 3 months difference correctly in my where clause?

2) Which function is better and return results faster in terms of performance?

Comment: share with data where you got different result

Answer (score 6):

`DATEDIFF` counts the number of "ticks" between 2 datetimes. So, for example `DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2019-01-31T23:59:59','2019-02-01T00:00:00')` returns `1`, even though only 1 second has passed; the month has changed (so one "tick" has occured).

For the perspective of what is "better", that depends on your requirement, however, `WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,order_date_time,GETDATE()) <= 3` is not advisable here, as it's non-SARGable. This is because `order_date_time` is contained within the function `DATEDIFF`.

I would use `WHERE order_date_time >= DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE())` (assuming you want rows where `order_date_time` is in the last 3 months).

Comment: Hi @Larnu thank you for the answer. One question - what do you mean by "ticks" in this context? Are you talking about rows? AND, what is " non-SARGable"? Also - in my above 2 where clauses, both are calculating 3 months difference or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: He means moments of change, time border limits, this kind of thing. How many times a change from a previous month value to the next one occurs. That's what datediff counts.

Comment: @kuml actually, they aren't both calculating 3 months difference. `DATEDIFF` is providing rows where the month itself was 3 months or less. So, on a the date 30 April 2019, it would be 01 January - 30 April inclusive. The other is where the date is more than or equal to the date 3 months ago; so using the same data again would be 30 January to 30 April inclusive. That isn't the same. By "tick" i mean that the value has changed, a boundariy has passed. In the example, the month boundary was passed. SARGan;e means "Searchable ARGument(s)", a non-SARGable query cannot use indexes on a table.

Answer (score 4):

These are your conditions:

```
WHERE order_date_time >= DateAdd(month, -3, getdate())
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, order_date_time, GetDate()) <= 3
```

The most important thing . . . These do different things.  The first goes back three months.  So, if today is April 15th, then it takes everything after Jan 15th.

The second looks at *month boundaries*.  So, it counts all of the January the same way and takes all values since Jan 1.

Although you should use the version you need, the first version is much, much better.  Basically, it can make use of indexes and partitions.  The function call `DATEDIFF()` makes it hard (impossible?) for the optimizer to use indexes on `order_date_time`.

If you intend the second form, I would recommend rephrasing it as something like this:

```
WHERE order_date_time >= datefromparts(year(dateAdd(month, -3, getdate())), month(dateAdd(month, -3, getdate())), 1)
```

Comment: Why the question mark (impossible?) Gordon? Isn't it a given than indexes do not work when functions are applied to the data? I've read so everywhere....probably including your posts.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis your answer def helped in understand the difference. I get it now,   DateAdd(month, -3, getdate()) will be always calculative relative cycle of exact 3 months from today's day. This is exactly what I need as I need to be able to run this query next month so calculation of 3 months from that date should be calculated while i see how datediff is calculating months (irrespective of today's date)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . Two reasons.  First, indexes are used with `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` (specifically one to `date` as far as I know).  Second, it should actually be possible, if something is known about the function.  I'm not aware of any databases that implement that logic, however.